# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An error occurred while setting up the GSS Encoded connection. Error while connecting on Postgres/Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

Issue while connecting to Postgres/Greenplum.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An error occurred while setting up the GSS Encoded connection.
```

I am using same connection file and was working fine till postgres 11/Greenplum v5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL 12 and later now allow GSSAPI encrypted connections. This parameter controls whether to enforce using GSSAPI encryption or not.

If encryption is not configured, should be disabled by setting JDBC connection parameter
**gssEncMode=disable**

Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6323207